# Grab all files in dir with specific extension regardless of extension case (case insensitive extensions) Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby what is the right way to get all the files in the directory with a certain extension regardless of the extension case?

For example, say I have the directory `~/myDir` and it has files `file1.JPG`, `file2.jpg`, `noFile.png` and `file3.jpg`. I would like to grab only the jpg files. I was using:

```
results = Dir[File.join(Dir.home, 'myDir', '*.jpg')].sort
```

but this leaves off `file1`.

I don't want a hacky solution like checking the files individually while forcing each to uppercase before checking. I definitely do not want something nasty like grabbing the files with extensions `JPG`, `JPg`, `Jpg`, `jpg`, `jpG`, and `jPG`.

Please include the supported version in your answers if it isn't backward-compatible with older version. I am on `1.9.3` but others may not be.

Comment: I am surprised this isn't already SO. It seems like a common situation with a not so obvious solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Dir.glob` and pass it `File::FNM_CASEFOLD` as the second param to tell it to ignore the case. So that gives us:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(Dir.home, 'myDir', "*.jpg"), File::FNM_CASEFOLD).sort
```

I found this solution in [this post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/04/14/case-insensitive-dir-glob-in-ruby-really-it-has-to-be-that-cryptic/) where Derick Bailey talks about [this post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/119964).

I am not sure if it works in all version but if anyone knows let me know and I will update it here. Trans in the last link in this post makes it seem like it wasn't always supported by saying "the docs said '(so+File::FNM_CASEFOLD+ is ignored)' ".

Comment: mentioned here although - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html#method-c-fnmatch

Comment: @ArupRakshit I thought about linking to that. It took me finding the post to realize that the docs kind of told me this. I saw the `File.FNM_CASEFOLD` used with `fnmatch` but this just returns a bool. I didn't know we could pass these to glob though until I read this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob  I am new to ruby. :/

Comment: Taking line from [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) **Note that this pattern is not a regexp, it’s closer to a shell glob. See `File.fnmatch` for the meaning of the flags parameter.**

Comment: This no longer works on 3.1 as of https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4583 which brings the `Dir.glob` behaviour inline with what the docs have been saying for years https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/File/File/Constants.html#FNM_CASEFOLD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab only files with the 'jpg' extension regardless of case (e.g. JPG, Jpg, jpg, ...) you can use:

```
files = Dir.glob("*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think DutGRIFF's answer is the way to go but as an additional option you can use this approach too:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(Dir.home, 'myDir', "*")).grep(/\.jpg\z/i).sort
```